# Qt / QRegularExpression - Can't capture all results, only 1st instance, why?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

I am trying to get some text surrounded by `<td>` tags. My problem is that I am able to fetch the first result only, and can't get others.

From the following HTML, I only get the 1st result which is this text:

> Student Name

But all other attempts to capture the rest of the needed text are empty, null. Why is that & what am I doing wrong?

**Text for regular expression to work on:**

```html
<table width="52%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#999999">Result</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="22%"><strong>Student ID</strong></td>
    <td width="78%">13/0003337/99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Student Name</strong></td>
    <td>Alaa Salah Yousuf Omer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>College</strong></td>
    <td>Medicine & General Surgery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Subspecialty</strong></td>
    <td>General</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Semester</strong></td>
    <td>Fourth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>State</strong></td>
    <td>Pass</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Semester's GPA</strong></td>
    <td>2.89</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Overall GPA</strong></td>
    <td>3.13</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

---

**My code:**

```
QString resultHTML = "A variable containing the html code written above."

QRegularExpression regex("<td>(.*)</td>", QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(resultHTML);

// I only get the 1st result logged withing debugger
for(int x = 0; x <= match.capturedLength(); x++)
{
    qDebug() << match.captured(x);
}

// This here doesn't get me anything, null!
_studentName = match.captured(2);
_semesterWritten = match.captured(8);
_stateWritten = match.captured(10);
_currentGPA = match.captured(12);
_overallGPA = match.captured(14);
```

Comment: Please, don't parse HTML by using regular expressions!

Comment: @peppe Yeah for sure, but when working with small amounts of data I just prefer to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to apply what Perl refers to as the **global** regex flag/modifier, which means, continue looking for matches after the first one has been found.

In order to do that with QT, try using [globalMatch()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#globalMatch) versus [match()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#match).

The former will return a [QRegularExpressionIterator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatchiterator.html), over which you can iterate to find all your matches.

**Additionally**, the ***** in **`<td>(.*)</td>`** is greedy, so it will find the first instance of **`<td>`**, then capture as *much* as possible (including most of your content and additional **`<td>`** tags), as long as it can find a **`</td>`** at the end.

There are different ways of avoiding this.  One way is to use **`<td>(.*?)</td>`**, which would capture as *little* as possible, as long as it can find a **`</td>`** at the end.  This would essentially capture everything within a single **`<td />`** tag, as long as there isn't another **`<td />`** nested further within (which doesn't look to be the case in your scenario).

**Additionally**, the [**QRegularExpression::MultilineOption**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum) PatternOption isn't needed here, since it pertains to the regex characters **^** and **$**, which you aren't using.

You might instead be interested in the **QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption** PatternOption, which includes newlines in dots, just in case those **`<td />`** tags, or the values contained within, happen to span multiple lines

Answer (score 2):

...Global matching is useful to find **all the occurrences** of a given regular expression inside a subject string...

```
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = regex.globalMatch(resultHTML);

while (i.hasNext()) 
{
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();        
    qDebug() << match.captured();
}
```